# I can write to SD cards only the first time I insert it after reboot

Tags: 18.04, mount, reboot, sd-card, read-only

After a reboot, I can insert a SD card and read/write normally. After extracting it, any subsequent SD card will be mounted as read only. My user belongs to the "disk" group. Trying to remount with rw doesn't work. This happens with the 6 or so SD cards I have. It is happening now with Ubuntu 18.04 both 64 and 32 bits versions on different computers. I also saw this problem with Ubuntu 16.04.

I am surprised this doesn't seem to be a common problem. So I am forced to "ask ubuntu". Any hints about how to improve things?

Thank you

Comment: In a terminal window `journalctl --follow` will show ongoing system log messages. Watch tem as you insert/remove your SD card.

Comment: What do you do to "extract" the card?  Do you get any popup saying it is safe to do so?

Comment: I extract the card using the file manager option, either Nautilus or Thunar.